# Take Keyboard Input Into Ember Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, components

I've created an ember component with a rectangular block inside a green canvas.

What I'm having trouble with is adding a keyboard-input command for A S D W to move the rectangle around the canvas. It's easy enough to do in regular javascript or jquery but inside the component model I'm a bit lost. Any help regarding the function would be very useful.

Linked here is an ember javascript bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/miyatoti/1/edit

Here is my present code of the component.

```
 App.BoxGameComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  tagName:'canvas',
  width: 325,
  height: 280,
  refresh:30,
  attributeBindings:['width', 'height'],
  stars:null,
  on:false,


  build: function(){
    var canvas = this.$()[0],
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        shippos = [150, 120],
        height = this.get('height'),
        width = this.get('width');


    this.set('shippos', shippos);   
    this.set('ctx', ctx);
    this.set('on', true);
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  kill: function(){
    this.set('on', false);
  }.on('willDestroyElement'),

  clear: function () {
    var ctx = this.get('ctx'),
        height = this.get('height'),
        width = this.get('width');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  },

    box: function () {

    var that = this;



    var ctx = this.get('ctx'),
        height = this.get('height'),
        width = this.get('width'),
        shippos = this.get('shippos');

    var posx = shippos[0],
        posy = shippos[1];

    ctx.rect(posx,posy,50,50);
    ctx.stroke();


  },



  game: function(){
    if(this.get('on')){
      this.loop();
    }
  }.observes('on'),
  loop: function () {
    var refreshRate = this.get('refresh');
    this.clear();
    this.box();
    if(this.get('on')){
      Em.run.later(this, this.loop, refreshRate);
    }
  }

});
```

If anyone can help I've been slamming my brain at this for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooking up keyup a canvas element is a bit trickier since the canvas doesn't get focus.  So you just hook up to the window (and then destroy it later).

```
$(window).on('keyup', {self:this}, this.handleKeyUp );
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/miyatoti/2/edit

Comment: Where do I put the actual if-then for mapping key presses to changing the coordinate values? And will code like....: document.onkeydown = function() {
    switch (window.event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
   posx--;
            break;
        case 39:
   posx++;
            break;
    }
};
 work?

Comment: I added the components scope as a property on the event, you would do it in the handleKeyUp method.  Here's a mini example. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/miyatoti/4/edit